# Why my HTTPS file download corrupts .zip files?

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, zip

I'm trying to download zip files from internet using following code:

```
public void getFile(String updateURL) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(updateURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpsConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpsConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    TrustModifier.relaxHostChecking(httpsConn);

    int responseCode = httpsConn.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        String fileName = "fileFromNet";

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(httpsConn.getInputStream());
            outputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }       

    }
    httpsConn.disconnect();
}
```

TrustModifier is a class used to solve the "trust issue": http://www.obsidianscheduler.com/blog/ignoring-self-signed-certificates-in-java/

The code above works well for zip files available via plain http or for non compressed files exposed via https but but if I try to download a zip file exposed via https endpoint only a small fragment of original file will be downloaded. I have tested with different download links from internet and always got the same result.

Does anybody has an idea what I've been doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`transferFrom()` must be called in a loop until the transfer is complete, and in this case the only way you can know that is by adding up the return values of `transferFrom()` until they equal the Content-length of the HTTP response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned, my code works well for all cases except when I try to download ZIP files via HTTPS. Well, having said that, I don't understand how the absence of that loop might cause problems with zip files (via https) and not with let's say plain texts?

Comment: You got lucky. It will fail as soon as you get a short read, which are apparently more likely with TLS. See the Javadoc. It isn't obliged to transfer the entire requested amount.

Answer (score -2):

Actually the problem was in the TrustModifier Class I was using to switch off the servier certificate check. Once I removed it because I didn't need it any longer (I took the certificate from server and put it in a local trust store), my problem was solved.

Comment: That would prevent you from getting a connection altogether. It wouldn't cause this problem.